# how to include html content in main page content location (pure html or use with angularjs)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, layout, bootstrap-4

**i have a project formed by html, js, bootstrap, angularjs.
my site have many pages that all pages have a template.
now, i think header ,navigation , footer and etc isn't reusable and i should write those any time.**

example in JSF :

```
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/template.xhtml"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">

    <ui:define name="title">
        New page title here
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="content">
        <h1>New content here</h1>
        <p>Blah blah</p>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

I do not know if I can use Angular to do this.
Thank you for any help you receive.

this is sample of my page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
    <title>main template</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
...
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app/styles/bootstrap4/bootstrap.min.css">    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app/styles/responsive.css">
    ...
</head>
<body>
<script src="app/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="app/styles/bootstrap4/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
....

<div class="super_container" ng-controller="showcaseController">
    <!-- Header -->
    <header class="header trans_300">
        <!-- Top Navigation -->
        <div class="top_nav">
            <div class="container">
                ....
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Main Navigation -->
        <div class="main_nav_container">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    ....
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

//content of page like this
    <div include-html="queryManagement.html"></div>  // <<---- url clicked
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.angular.js"></script>
<script src="app/apps/app.js"></script>
.....

</body>
</html>
```

tip:

> Pages are clicked on the bar, and they look like they are on the page.
>   But in any case, the layout page is loaded as a main page, which opens
>   the content of the selected page within itself.

Comment: This question is **very broad**.

Comment: if you have any git project for sample please present to me

Comment: This site is for **asking coding questions**. Not for getting others write code for you.

Comment: I know what this site is for. I also do not expect to write code for me. I think my question is clear enough. If your information is not enough, let others answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found solution with angularjs.

in layout page:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="FirstPage">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app/styles/bootstrap4/bootstrap.min.css">
....
</head>
<body>
<script src="app/styles/bootstrap4/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
.....
<div class="super_container" ng-controller="layout">
    <!-- Header -->
    <header class="header trans_300">
        <!-- Top Navigation -->
        <div class="top_nav">
            <div class="container">
                    ......
                 <nav class="navbar">
                            <ul class="navbar_menu">
                 look ng-click  <li><a href="#" ng-click="loadContent('page1.html')">link 1</a></li>
                 look ng-click  <li><a href="#" ng-click="loadContent('page2.html')">link 2</a></li>
                            </ul>
                         </div>
                 </nav>
....
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <!--<div ng-bind-html="contentUri"/>-->
    <div id="ext-content" ng-include="contentUri"/> //<== use ng-include for content
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="app/apps/app.js"></script>
....
</body>
</html>
```

and then in js:

```
app.controller("layout", function ($scope, client, esFactory) {

    $scope.contentUri = '';

    $scope.loadContent = function (uri) {
        $scope.contentUri = uri;
    }
});
```

this worked for me